# Movie where countries kill their citizens to combat overpopulation

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I remember seeing a trailer for this movie and reading its Wikipedia summary. Basically, the premise is that the world is plagued by overpopulation, and so the UN passes a resolution that this is to be combatted by killing off excess population. The movie takes place in the United States, the government of which decides which children to kill off by administering a test. The trailer shows a kid with his/her mother rehearsing for the test, with the mother asking "How many sides does a pentagon (Or maybe some other shape) have", and the kid replying "five (Or the appropriate number if it is some other shape)". The next question is "What causes disease?", to which the kid answers "Bacteria". From the Wikipedia summary, I think the mother tries to have her kid cheat by using a device hidden in a pair of glasses. The kid still fails the test and, after many events in the movie, is captured by the authorities. It is revealed, however, that the US government does not kill off those who fail the test (But it has managed to convince the outside world that it does), but rather, keeps them isolated in an underground complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is [The Thinning](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi1149679129?playlistId=tt5254868&ref_=tt_ov_vi)

> In a future, overcrowded, dystopian society, students with the lowest
> test scores are culled. Two students discover errors with the test.

Trailer with the quotes about pentagon:

Found in https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=overpopulation

Comment: Does the cast consist entirely of YouTubers?

Comment: @Valorum from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thinning: Peyton List, Calum Worthy, Ryan Newman and so on.

Comment: So yes, then, basically.

Comment: @Valorum - It's a film made by YouTube, so that explains it. You'd think that as it's the first original movie released by YouTube would be better known, but it seems to have been completely ignored by critics and anyone who isn't a fan of one of the stars.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - Ah, now that would certainly explain it. I just thought it had a micro-budget and poor casting

Comment: At risk being called off topic, might the reason it wasn't a success be that the plot appears self-defeating?

Keeping people isolated in an underground complex does nothing to address the population level, making the whole idea pointless… Unless, of course, the complex is a death camp which would make the whole thing worse, wouldn't it?